# How do I undo meta class changes after executing GroovyShell?

Tags: groovy, metaprogramming

For example, if I execute a Groovy script, which modifies the String meta class, adding a method foo()

```
GroovyShell shell1 = new GroovyShell();
shell1.evaluate("String.metaClass.foo = {-> delegate.toUpperCase()}");
```

when I create a new shell after that and execute it, the changes are still there

```
GroovyShell shell2 = new GroovyShell();
Object result = shell2.evaluate("'a'.foo()");
```

Is there a way to undo all meta class changes after executing the GroovyShell? I tried

```
shell1.getClassLoader().clearCache();
```

and

```
shell1.resetLoadedClasses();
```

but that did not make a change.

Comment: Can I do this with some classloader messing?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass(String.class);
```

to revert all changes made to the String meta class.

Alternatively you could only change the meta class of a certain String instance, thus not all instances of String would be affected.

Comment: Thanks. But what, if I don't know what meta class changes have been made. Think of an application like the Groovy Web Console, where different users execute Groovy scripts. I want these users not to interfere.

Comment: See my answer below, which solves your problem of not knowing which metaclasses have changed.

Answer (score 3):

You can use MetaClassRegistryCleaner too.

Before doing some metaclass changes, you can do

```
MetaClassRegistryCleaner registryCleaner = MetaClassRegistryCleaner.createAndRegister()
GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.addMetaClassRegistryChangeEventListener(registryCleaner)
```

And when you want to reset the metaclass changes to the state they were earlier.

You can do

```
registryCleaner.clean()  
GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClassRegistryChangeEventListener(registryCleaner)
```

This way you can reset all the metaclass changes made during the duration.

Answer (score 1):

I realise that this is a somewhat older question, but it's the first result on Google when I was searching for exactly the same issue.

The solution I chose was to put groovy into a new classloader (by using plexus-classworlds), so when the script is finished, the classloader is disposed (and so any changes to the metaclass are also disposed).

Comment: @JohnMercier did not my answer above help ?

Comment: This is a better approach than registry cleaning in many ways, especially to allow concurrent executions.