# methodMissing closure - not encapsulated?

Tags: groovy

I understand groovy basics - and closures...

I am trying to call groovy from java:

// Patient.java

```
public class Patient {  
    //... other data  
    private Map<String, String> attribStore = new HashMap<String,String>();  
    // getters/setters for attribStore omitted  

    public void addAttribute(String key, String val) {
        if (!attribStore.containsKey(key)) {
            attribStore.put(key, val);
        }
    }
```

// GroovyHelper.java

```
public class GroovyHelper {
    private String codeSnippet; // groovy script code

    public String evaluateSnippetToString(Binding binding) {
        addMethodMissingHandler();
        GroovyShell shell = createGroovyShell(binding);
        Object result = shell.evaluate(codeSnippet);
        return result.toString();
    }

    // installs a patient in the binding - accesses the patient  
    // attribStore from groovy
    // The missing method is used to create an "attribute" i.e.
    // a (key,val) pair in the patient map 
    private void addMethodMissingHandler() {
        codeSnippet = "def attribStore = p.getAttribStore();\n"
        + "Patient.metaClass.methodMissing = \n{"
        + " String methodName, args -> \n"
        + "methodName = methodName.replaceFirst(/^get/, '');\n"  
        + "def attrib = methodName[0].toLowerCase() + methodName.substring(1);\n"
        + "if (!attribStore.containsKey(attrib)) { attribStore[attrib] = '0'; }\n"
        + "return attribStore[attrib]; \n" + "}\n" + codeSnippet;
    }  
}
```

// junit test code

```
private Patient p;
private Binding binding;
private GroovyHelper gh;

    @Before 
    public void init() {
        p = new PatientBuilder().build();
        binding = new Binding();
        binding.setVariable("p", p);
        gh = new GroovyHelper();
    }

    @Test //passes
    public void testPopulatePatientAttribStore() throws Exception {
        p.addAttribute("xyz", "4");
        gh.setCodeSnippet("p.getXyz()");
        gh.evaluateSnippetToString(binding);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGroovy() throws Exception {
        Binding binding = new Binding();
        binding.setVariable("p", new Patient()); // new patient
        p.addAttribute("xyz", "9");

        GroovyShell gs1 = new GroovyShell(binding);

        assertEquals("9", gs1.evaluate("p.getXyz()")); // fails??? - expected: <[9]> but was: <[4]>
    }
```

My question is - is the closure holding on to the attribute store of an earlier binding?
    What exactly is happening here?
Apologies all for the longish code - I worked on it
- cut down irrelevant code
to shrink it to a minimum - any pointer, "more reading to do" hints?

Comment: Actually the second test method, testGroovy, should have resulted in MissingMethodException... The odd part is, ran alone, it works fine (i.e. results in the exception)  - ran together as a suit of tests - it fails...

Answer (score 1):

I think part of the problem is that you're creating a `methodMissing` in the `Patient` metaclass that delegates to the `attribStore` of one specific patient.  I would approach the problem in a different way - is it an option to implement `methodMissing` directly in the `Patient` class itself?

```
public class Patient {
  // other members as before

  public Object methodMissing(String name, Object[] args) {
    if(name != null && name.startsWith("get") && name.length() > 3) {
      String attrName = name.substring(3,1).toLowerCase() + name.substring(4);
      addAttribute(attrName, "0");
      return attribStore.get(attrName);
    } else {
      throw new MissingMethodException(name, this.getClass(), args);
    }
  }
}
```

Or if this is not an option, could you implement the `GroovyHelper` class in Groovy (compile it using groovyc and you can call into it from Java the same as any Java class)?

```
public class GroovyHelper {
    static {
      // add a methodMissing to the Patient metaclass
      Patient.metaClass.methodMissing = { String name, args ->
        if(name?.startsWith("get") && name.length() > 3) {
          String attrName = name.substring(3,1).toLowerCase() + name.substring(4)
          // delegate here is the particular Patient instance on which the
          // missing method call was made
          delegate.addAttribute(attrName, "0")
          return delegate.attribStore[attrName];
        } else {
          throw new MissingMethodException(name, this.getClass(), args);
        }
      }
    }

    private String codeSnippet // groovy script code

    public String evaluateSnippetToString(Binding binding) {
        GroovyShell shell = createGroovyShell(binding)
        Object result = shell.evaluate(codeSnippet)
        return result.toString()
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Ian and Brian, Thank you so much for taking the time to look at the problem. I am updating my question...

Comment: Yes - moving the methodMissing to Patient is certainly possible... Will try it out...

Answer (score 0):

It certainly appears that the MetaClass for `Patient` is surviving b/w `GroovyShell` runs -  the [MetaClassRegistry](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/lang/MetaClassRegistry.html) may be a singleton and thus live for the life of the classloader or JVM (can't quite think through how this works in the JVM at the moment).  And, as you suggest, I believe your `methodMissing` closure closes around the `attribStore` variable it originally gets.  (a quick test seems to indicate you should have access to the `p` in the binding from within that closure.  I'm guessing you tried that and it didn't work?).  One option might be to forcibly [remove the MetaClass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612569/how-do-i-undo-meta-class-changes-after-executing-groovyshell) from `Patient` after each test in a teardown method.